# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors,org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um9Li.png)I have integrate sdk in my project then the error is showing .."Manifest merger failed with multiple errors". How to remove this.I have already check and implement solution according to answer of stackoverflow but it can't resolve.All the activity is single declare in manifest.

In the manifest I declared " tools:replace="android:allowBackup" ",label ,icon and name all these apply but it can't resolve please provide any solution.

Comment: I think you put invalid dependency in your app.gradle check it and if required also remove it.

Comment: Please can you post the contents of your project's manifest file ?

Comment: or if required,you convert your project with "androidX"

Comment: Check all your xml files if it contain multiple <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> tags?

Answer (score 0):

Open your manifest file and click on bottom tab **Merged Manifest** there you will find reason for failure check below snap

[image]

Comment: Added a screenshot of Merged Manifest

Comment: I don't see replace property inside application tag

Comment: Sir this is the image url of manifest..https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um9Li.png

Comment: I seen image but I am saying that in application tag replace attribute is not there while you wrote that you added